# Сортировка чисел в массиве (JAVA) Покажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка

Tags: java, массивы

```
package arrays;
public class Arrays {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int[] ar = {12,-3,8,1,19,22,0};
    int temp;
    for(int i = 0; i<ar.length-1;i++) {
        if(ar[i]>ar[i+1]) {
            temp=ar[i+1];
            ar[i+1]=ar[i];
            ar[i]=temp;         
        }
    }
    //НЕ ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ ВЫВЕСТИ ЧИСЛА В ОТСОРТИРОВАННОМ ПОРЯДКЕ
}
for(int i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(ar[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Напишите, что происходит не так. Иначе не ясно какая ошибка имеется ввиду.

Comment: Не получается вывести числа в отсортированном порядке

Comment: На данный момент код не компилируется. Почитайте как создать [МСВП](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Вы пробегаетесь одним циклом, меняя местами соседние элементы. Поставьте флаг и выполнйете цикл до тех пор, пока пройдя по нему не поменяюсься местами элементы.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] ar = {12,-3,8,1,19,22,0};
    int temp;
    boolean flag = true;

    while (flag) {
        flag = false;

        for(int i = 0; i<ar.length-1;i++){
            if(ar[i]>ar[i+1]){
                temp=ar[i+1];
                ar[i+1]=ar[i];
                ar[i]=temp;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<ar.length;i++){
        System.out.print(ar[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Я полагаю, что вы пытаесь реализовать алгоритм сортировки "пузырек". Ксли так, то он должен выглядить как то вот так.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] ar = {12,-3,8,1,19,22,0};
    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < (ar.length - i); j++) {
            if(ar[j - 1] > ar[j]){
                temp=ar[j-1];
                ar[j-1]=ar[j];
                ar[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<ar.length;i++){
        System.out.print(ar[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Конечно, знание алгоритмов сортировки - это хорошо, но на практике лучше не изобретать велосипед, а использовать `Arrays.sort()` или `Collections.sort()` для коллекций :)